# Volume Control Stopped Working - always max voume

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, radeon

A few days ago out of nowhere I noticed my volume control stopped working. The audio itself works fine, but changing the volume does not actually do anything. Even if you mute it, it still plays all audio at max volume.

I tried pulseaudio --start but it did not help.
I am using radeon GPU so I notice my bootloader starts radeon audio, which may be why pulseaudio isn't working? I don't know much about this audi

Answer (score 1):

Try this: go to **System** > **Preferences** > **Sound**, then in the **Output tab**, select a device different from the selected one, until you find one working together with the global volume control.